# Template button in iOS

Tags: ios, interface

I have a complex button design (labels and subviews with lots of various images and settings) and I would like to use it all over the place. Copying and pasting works initially, but what if i want to change some detail and that has to effect bunch of buttons. Seems like a lot of work. Is there a better way? Some sort of template button system?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what a `.xib` file is for. Design the whole thing in its own `.xib`. Then, wherever it is needed, load that nib, extract the button, and put it into the interface. This gives you a fresh copy each time. Of course, you will have to do that in code, but it isn't as bad as you might suppose; for example, you could use a plain placeholder button in the storyboard, so that you are doing a simple replacement every time.

Another alternative might be to use a button subclass and use the `appearance` proxy to make your configurations in code, once, as the app launches; but that is not as powerful or as flexible as using a nib, because not everything that you want to say can be said through the `appearance` proxy.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks! Do you have any examples on how to do the first suggestion?

Comment: Also, how should I setup button callbacks? Should I set them up in interface builder and copy whatever placeholder buttons does or should I just do it all in code?

Comment: You'll have to hook up the button's target-action in code. But that's no big deal because you're already fetching the button out of the nib in code and putting it into the interface in code. :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd read my book. :) Start here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_making_and_loading_a_nib ... and read through to the end of the next section, where I extract the label from the nib and put it into the interface. That's the kind of thing you're going to be doing.